# Ricoh SP 211SU Driver

Tags: drivers, printing, ricoh

I want my Ricoh SP 211SU printer to work, but there is no driver. I am Using 14.04 LTS. Can anyone help me with a driver or an instruction?

Answer (score 1):

1. connect it via USB
2. sytem settings -> Printers -> Add -> ricoh sp 211su ->"Generic" -> "PCL 6/PCL XL"

(Follow Recommended options)