# How-to Ricoh SP 211SF driver installation

Tags: drivers, printing, 16.10, ricoh

Recently I installed Ubuntu on my laptop as the only OS, Unfortunately my printer **Ricoh Sp 211 sf** doesn't have an official Driver so I can't use it.

Some additional info. I'm running:

- Ubuntu 16.10 on
- Intel core i7 processor
- 64bit architecture
- Acer BYOC (bios)

  1. I tried using the generic option from the chose printer type.
  2. I Tried using searching in the ricoh section but I can't find my
     model.
  3. I Searched online and the closest thing I found online is [Link to
     external site on support.ricoh.com](http://op-drv-ds1.support.ricoh.com/seresBB/servlet/VSORPageServlet?OBJPATH=bb/pub_e/dr_ut_e/0001269/0001269744/V4000/r68485en.tar&EURA=bb/html/dr_ut_e/re1/resource/eula_unixfilter.txt&VSORSELFWID=WRU001&VSORSELNWID=), which is a unix Driver for
     212W.

i tried running it but (probably they're not compatible with my system) it doesn't work.

**Does anybody know how to install the driver for this printer? If yes can you please explain me in a easy way how to do it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/849814/ricoh-sp-212sfnw-drivers-install?rq=1

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate I have the sp211sf not the sp212spnw

Comment: follow steps in this question it works for all Richo SP printers https://askubuntu.com/questions/760928/ricoh-sp-211su-driver/858648#858648